# How to know when a new object is created in Python on contrary to just assigning a variable to the same object

Tags: python, pointers, variables

So this question is not a super concrete question but I can give some examples. I am very afraid of Python since you never know when a variable is pointing at a new object or just have two variables pointing at the same object.

For example I am scared of assigning like this:

```
def function(self):
    number = self.value
    return number
```

In this case I don't want number to change if I change self.value.

Also just copying lists like:

```
list = [1,2,3]
list2 = list
```

In this case if I change list, list2 will also be changed which is not desirable. Why would I copy it if i don't want it to be a new variable!

Anyway, I just wonder if anybody knows a safe method to create new variables in these cases or maybe has a complete explanation of when a new object is created and when two variables point at the same object. I want to code in peace and not worry about this all the time because my code is big and I can't sit and check which variables have changed and which have not after every calculation.

The question is related to mutability and immutability so the link to the question:
[Immutable vs Mutable types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8056130/immutable-vs-mutable-types),
might be good but this is another way of asking the question which might be helpful for some. Also this is more focused on avoiding mutating.

Comment: Simple rule: assignment **never** creates a new object. Always, after the assignment, the name on the left simply refers to the object on the right.

Comment: So I must always assign a value to a new variable A, and then i can assign a value from variable B to A, and this will always create a copy of the object?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Immutable vs Mutable types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8056130/immutable-vs-mutable-types)

Comment: @KanervaPeter - No, assigning from B to A will never create a copy of the object. But see the accepted answer and the duplicate question listed above for a more complete explanation.

Comment: How about initiating a new class object with some initiate parameters. If I just pass the name of the variable to the constructor parameter. Is the object just assigned or does it create a new object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, like in many languages, some objects are said to be mutable and some are said to be immutable. An immutable object is an object that once created cannot change, such as an `int`.

```
x = 3
y = x
```

In the previous example both `x` and `y` *point* to the same object, but since `3` is immutable, it is not a problem.

Some other objects are mutable, such as a `list`. It means there are ways to change their value.

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3]
l2 = l1 # This does not copy the object, it simply makes the name l2 point to it
```

Here the exact same as for the `int` happens, both variables point to the same object, but there exist a way to change that object. By example by doing `l2.append(4)`.

The best way to avoid what you are talking about here is by adopting good practices. By example, keep your function pure and make it clear when they are not.

A pure function is a function that has no side effects and returns a brand new object. So it does not *mutate* the arguments then return them, but copy them and return a new one.

In the example you gave, a way to achieve that would be to use `deepcopy`.

```
from copy import deepcopy

l1 = [1, 2, 3]
l2 = deepcopy(l1) # Here deepcopy actually created a new object and returned it
```

I encourage you to read about [which objects are mutable and which are not](https://codehabitude.com/2013/12/24/python-objects-mutable-vs-immutable/) and then adjust your practices based on that new knowledge.

Comment: Can deepcopy be used on all objects and types?

Comment: It can on all objects which have a `__deepcopy__` function. All `deepcopy` does is call that method.

Comment: I really like this deepcopy function. It really takes all my worries away x))! It's a wonder I've never come across it before and I've been using python for some years now.